# Active MQ not working under Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

When trying to connect to a queue on Active MQ I am receiving the following error message.

```
Failed to create route ...because of Failed to resolve endpoint: amq://queue:ROBOMQ.TO.MPM due to: Password must also be provided when using username/password as credentials.
```

The declaration for the AMQ bean in the Camel XML below. The has been working for many months but now has stopped.

```
<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616" />
    <property name="userName" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the Camel version has changed from 2.16 to 2.18 within the project and thus the bean declaration needs to also change, with the Connection Factory being explicitly defined.

FROM:

```
<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616" />
    <property name="userName" value="system" />
    <property name="password" value="manager" />
```

TO:

```
<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616" />
        <property name="userName" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="manager" />
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```